# Celcius to Fahr using methods but method says undefined

Tags: java

I need help calling my method. It says `"the method fahrtoCel" is undefined for the "TempConversion"`.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class TempConversion {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        System.out.println("===CONVERTING TEMPERATURE=====");
        ConvertTemp();
    }

        private static void ConvertTemp(){
            Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.println("Press 1: Convert Celcius to Fahrenheit\nPress 2: Convert Fahrenheit to Celcius\n");
            int select = s.nextInt();

            if (select==1){
                System.out.print("Enter the fahrenheit: "); 
                celtoFahr();
            }   else if (select==2){
                System.out.print("Enter the celcius: ");
                fahrtoCel();
            }   else{
                System.out.println("exit");

            }

            private static void celtoFahr(){
                double temperature = s.nextDouble();
                double celcius = 5.0/9.0*(temperature-32);

            }
            private static void fahrtoCel(){
                double temperature = s.nextDouble();
                double fahrenheit = 9.0/5.0*(temperature+32);
            }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a closing `}`

```
private static void ConvertTemp(){
    Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Press 1: Convert Celcius to Fahrenheit\nPress 2: Convert Fahrenheit to Celcius\n");
    int select = s.nextInt();

    if (select==1){
        System.out.print("Enter the fahrenheit: "); 
        celtoFahr();
    }   else if (select==2){
        System.out.print("Enter the celcius: ");
        fahrtoCel();
    }   else{
        System.out.println("exit");

    }

    // add closing curly
   }
    private static void celtoFahr(){
    ...
```

If you do however, `s` will be out of scope so change your method to accept the Scanner.

e.g.

```
private static void ConvertTemp(){
    Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
     ....
        celtoFahr(s);
    ....
}

private static void celtoFahr(Scanner s){
     ....
}
```

If you use an IDE like Eclipse this error will be immediately obvious